# tag no muestra el texto (vacío) en Select2 dinámico con Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, select2

Quiero mostrar opciones pre-seleccionadas, pero al hacerlo en cuanto carga el select2 no me muestra el texto en los tags que se inician.

Si alguien pudiera decirme que tengo mal en mi código o como funciona el usar trigger('change') exactamente!

El texto lo obtengo de mi ajax como json, cuando yo lo selecciono manualmente me funciona bien, pero al inicializarlos por defecto no me muestra el texto. Llevo semanas intentando resolverlo, ¿Alguien?

```
var idsResponsables = "",
    x = "",
    res = "";
if (document.getElementById('responsables') !== null) {
    idsResponsables = document.getElementById('responsables').value;
    x = idsResponsables.split(",");
    var options = "";
    for (var i = 1; i < x.length - 1; i++) {
        options += "<option value='" + x[i] + "'>Texto Cualquiera</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("destinatarios").innerHTML = options;
}

var datos = [];
var _tags = $("#select option").each(function() {
    datos.push($(this).val());
});

var $tagsControl = $("#select").select2({
    tags: true,
    ajax: {
        url: "ajaxSearchUsers.jsp",
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 250,
        data: function(params) {
            return {
                q: params.term, // search term
                page: params.page
            };
        },
        processResults: function(data, params) {
            params.page = params.page || 1;
            return {
                results: data.items,
                pagination: {
                    more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                }
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
        return markup;
    },
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    templateResult: formatRepo,
    templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
});

$tagsControl.val(datos).trigger("change");
```

Estos son mis métodos de formatRepo y formatRepoSelection

```
function formatRepo(repo) {
    if (repo.loading)
        return repo.text;

    var markup = "<div class='select2-result-repository clearfix'>" +
        "<div class='select2-result-repository__meta'>" +
        "<div class='select2-result-repository__title'><i class='fa fa-user'></i> " + repo.name + "</div>";

    if (repo.email) {
        markup += "<div class='select2-result-repository__description'><i class='fa fa-envelope'></i> " + repo.email + "</div>";
    }

    markup += "" +
        "</div></div>";

    return markup;
}

function formatRepoSelection(repo) {
    return repo.name;
}
```

Manualmente todo me funciona bien, solo me da error cuando los quiero inicializar, me muestra los tags de la siguiente manera:

[image: Tags sin texto alguno]

Comment: te muestra algún error en la consola del navegador?

Comment: @JuanGlezz Solo muestra uno 'unreachable code after return statement' ---> moment.min.js. No sé si tenga problema lo que quiero hacer con esa excepción.

Answer (score 1):

en base al error que te salio en consola puede que se deba al `quietMillis`

Si trabajas con la version 3.5.2 de select2 deberias checar esta documentacion:
[select2 3.5.2](http://select2.github.io/select2/index.html)

Y en base a esa version tu codigo tiene un problema en la opcion ajax:

```
var $tagsControl = $("#select").select2({
    tags: true,
    ajax: {
        url: "ajaxSearchUsers.jsp",
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term, // search term
                page: params.page
                };
        },
        //processResults: function (data, params) {//tu error
        results: function (data, params) {
            params.page = params.page || 1;
            return {
                results: data.items,
                pagination: {
                    more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                }
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
        return markup;
    },                       
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    templateResult: formatRepo,
    templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
});
```

Si trabajas con la version 4.0 esta es tu documentacion: [select2 4.0.3](http://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax)

Y tu problema seria con `quietMillis`

```
var $tagsControl = $("#select").select2({
    tags: true,
    ajax: {
        url: "ajaxSearchUsers.jsp",
        dataType: 'json',
        //quietMillis: 250,//tu problema
        delay:250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term, // search term
                page: params.page
                };
        },
        //processResults: function (data, params) {//tu error
        results: function (data, params) {
            params.page = params.page || 1;
            return {
                results: data.items,
                pagination: {
                    more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                }
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
        return markup;
    },                       
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    templateResult: formatRepo,
    templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
});
```

**Edit**
en el change tambien esta incorrecto;
select2 4.0.3:

```
$tagsControl.on("change", function (e) { 
    $(".js-example-data-array-selected").select2({
        data: datos
    }) 
});
```

En la version 3.5.2 busca el apartado events.

Comment: Ya he actualizado a la versión Select2 4.0.3 y he leído la documentación y veo que mi select2 es parecido al del ejemplo que proveen a diferencia que el mío es múltiple, donde creo tal vez esté mi problema. Al igual, he probado cambiar el "change", pero sigue sin aparecer el texto en los tags. Y lo del quietMillis si solucionó el WARNING que me mandaba en consola.
Tienes otra idea de que ocurra? y gracias por tomarte la molestia @JuanGlezz

Comment: @NestorLópez el que no aparezcan los nombres en el `select` puede ser porque no este insertando los datos correctamente intenta poner `console.log(datos)` dentro de las funciones de ajax puede que no este tomando los valores correctamente del arreglo o el arreglo este vacio

Comment: Los datos que me trae el ajax son correctos. Cuando hago el proceso de buscar en el `select` sí pone el tag como debe de ser, solo tengo el error al momento de inicializarlos por defecto. Crees que tenga que ver con que solo mando el `id` y tenga que mandar tanto el `id` como el texto a mostrar en `datos`?

Comment: @NestorLópez puede ser que si ese sea el otro problema, porque mira así es como recibe un arreglo y muestra los datos el select `[{ id: 0, text: 'enhancement' }, { id: 1, text: 'bug' }]` es un arreglo de JSON, lo cual imagino que algo así recibe el arreglo